# Unable to get the pre processor options in visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

hi folks sorry to buggy you but i tried several type of project, and never have the C++ pre compiler options in the properties of my project,

i have already a .cpp program loaded, but there is no mention of "C++" in the project properties left pane

Comment: What project type are you hoping to use, Console Application or something different?

Answer (score 0):

In solution explorer, with your solution loaded, you'll see the projects that form your solution. (In my example I created a new C++ Console Application)

If you select your c++ project in the 'Solution Explorer' window, right-click, in the context menu towards the bottom there will be an option for "Properties".

This will open up the project properties, and in that dialog is a section for C/C++ under 'Configuration Properties'.

There you will find all the C++ options that you need.